What is the difference between com.android.application and com.android.tools?
I am currently studying Google's nowinandroid app and trying to figure out how the project is structured. I'm looking at the app's build.gradle.kt file:
https://github.com/android/nowinandroid/blob/main/app/build.gradle.kts
and also looking at the convention modules build.gradle.kt:
https://github.com/android/nowinandroid/blob/main/build-logic/convention/build.gradle.kts.
I'm getting confused by what the difference between com.android.tools.build dependency is in the build-logic module's build.gradle.kt vs the app module's com.android.application plugin.
I figured out that com.android.tools.build is needed to gain access to the ApplicationExtension type. Without com.android.tools.build as a dependency, this file https://github.com/android/nowinandroid/blob/main/build-logic/convention/src/main/kotlin/AndroidApplicationComposeConventionPlugin.kt will throw an error about ApplicationExtension not being found.
I googled ApplicationExtension and it seems to be included as part of the Android Gradle Plugin(com.android.application): https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.1/com/android/build/api/dsl/ApplicationExtension.
So if ApplicationExtension is part of the com.android.application plugin, why do I need the com.android.tools.build dependency?
